# Selenium can't find the right locator [JAVA]

Tags: java, selenium, youtube

So I am just trying to find the right locator for my first automation test in Java using Selenium.

Here's the code:

```
public class Main1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Filip\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver obj = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(obj, 15);
        By cookies_accept = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"introAgreeButton\"]");

        obj.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De2SF7wy3uE");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dismiss-button\"]")));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dismiss-button\"]")));
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dismiss-button\"]")).click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cookies_accept)).click();
    }
}
```

Error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]"}

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `//*` selects all elements in a document, you are targeting an attribute, you will want to be less selective and try target a level. Please post an example HTML

Comment: @KennethClark it's a youtube, I am trying to agree cookies pop up window. I managed to sign in, but can't make it to agree to cookies.

Comment: It might be 'iFrame'. You should 'switch' to the needed frame before clicking buttons. obj.switchTo().frame(obj.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));